# Shell Script OSX - VM Fusion (VMRun)

Tags: macos, shell, virtual-machine

I'm trying to create a shell script to check if VM is running on OSX if it's not currently running I want to start it, I have the way I've come up with to check if it's running, and the way to start it if it's not. What I do not have is the syntax to make it all work... Any help is appreciated:

## Command 1

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun list | grep -q ".vmx"
```

Which will return '.vmx' only if there is an active VM running on VMFusion. I want to use this command and make it conditional to use in correspondence with this command:

## Command 2

```
/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun -T fusion start "PATHTOVMXFILE/Windows 7.vmx"
```

Which will start the VM.

The logic would be:

```
infinite loop
{
Command 1
If the return of the Command 1 is not ".vmx"
then run Command 2
else 
do nothing
continue looping
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
while true; do
    command_one=$(/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun list | grep -q \".vmx\")
    if [ $command_one = ".vmx" ]; then
        $(/Applications/VMware\ Fusion.app/Contents/Library/vmrun -T fusion start \"PATHTOVMXFILE/Windows 7.vmx\")
    else
        sleep 1;
    fi
done
```

Comment: Basically man, thank you, only thing i'll be changing is it will execute the command if command_one != '.vmx" but I think I can handle that portion! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Great. If it works alright for you maybe you could mark it as solved? Thnx!

Comment: Done. Thanks again.